# Color histogram bars using stat_bin ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, statistics, r-markdown, histogram

I would like to change the fill and color of my histogram bars, However the current approach does not work,
I am using the following fill and color:

```
ggplot(dfAllCounts, aes(x=months)) +
  stat_bin(binwidth=6, geom="text", aes(label=after_stat(count)), vjust=-1, fill="#d2aa47", color = '#163B8B')
```

However, the actual plot is not displayed propertly:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Done!
Fixed with this:

````
br <- seq(0, 178, 10)
ggplot(dfAllCounts, aes(x=months)) +
  stat_bin(binwidth=6, fill="#d2aa47", color = '#163B8B', size = .8, alpha = 0.3) +
  stat_bin(binwidth=6, geom="text", aes(label=..count..), vjust=-1) +
  ylim(c(0, 175)) + 
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = br)```
````